# How to georeference a hand drawn map using QGIS or ArcGIS?

Tags: qgis

A Geoinformatics student here,  I have a hand drawn village map so how to the Georeference the map?

Comment: What format is your map? Have you scanned this in?

Comment: How accurate do you think it is? How much warping and bending and stretching will it need to map to the real world?

Comment: What single GIS software are you actually using when you try to do this?  Did you consult its documentation?

Comment: yes ,i have scanned map in jpeg format  but that is not a georeferenced . and i want to digitize the whole village map

Answer (score 2):

[ArcMap](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Georeferencing_a_raster_dataset)

1. Scan the image into the computer
2. Start ArcMap
3. Add a basemap and then zoom to the area you are going to georeference
4. Use the Georeferencing toolbar and follow the prompts

QGIS: 
See this response: [How to Georeference in QGIS 2.12.1 Lyon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177969/how-to-georeference-in-qgis-2-12-1-lyon?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

**ArcMap**

1. Open ArcMap
2. Add Data [image]
3. Find Your Scanned Image (I tend to use PNG)
4. Hit OK to the "Unknown Spatial Reference" Window[image]
5. Turn on the Georeferencing Toolbar
6. Zoom to the Desired Extent and Click "Fit to Display"[image]
7. You will see something like this (I am using my own made up images)[image]
8. Then Click Add Control Points to Start Positions Your Image Against Your Layers. *Always try to limit the number of control points you use (the less the better)*[image]

**Be sure to click the Georeferencing tab again (where you previously found "Fit to Display") and click "Update Georeferencing" when you are finished to save your image**

Hope this helped! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the map on the web, and if the site conditions apply, you could try using http://mapwarper.net/ .

> By uploading images to the website you agree that you allow anyone to view and use them, including changing control points etc.
>   So we recommend that you have permission to upload them. Uploading and making images available does not grant a copyright license to others. There is no guarantee about privacy or protection of images and metadata uploaded (see note below about personal data).

MapWarper allows for web-based georeferencing against the OpenStreetMap map tiles, so you'll be less successful if OSM does not have maps for your AOI.